# How do I map my connection string to my app_data folder rather than use an absolute path?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I have a connection string that includes the absolute path to my database.

Here's my connection string:

```
// removed
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I convert the absolute path to look at my app_data folder instead
   of adding a full string?
2. Is this a good /bad thing to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `|DataDirectory|` substitution string:

```
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|MyDb.mdf
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx#sectionSection2)